# How is funds in DAO treasury gets accumulated?

Tags: dapps, dao

Let's say I building DAO and I am curious to know how exactly is funds in treasury gets accumulated initially, when the DAO is at baby stage?

1. Should I alone need to fund treasury from scratch or is there any alternative
2. Let's say some VC funded my DAO, how is that VC gets compensated?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question heavily depends on what kind of DAO you are building. But general answers are:

1. As a DAO usually decides what happens with the treasury, the members of the DAO contribute to it. They are compensated with voting tokens or something else that is proportional to their contribution. In a [Moloch](https://molochdao.com/docs/introduction/wtf-is-moloch/) kind of DAO, the users have the ability to "ragequit", by which they exchange all of their voting tokens to corresponding portion of the treasury and exit it.
2. Similar to the first response, VC would get the voting tokens or the equivalent, unless they specify something else in the terms of funding. Let's say you have a weighted DAO voting where some votes are worth more than the others, they would probably want to have their votes be worth more.